# Office 2010 - I can't open multiple documents at once?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010

Is it just me or did Office 2010 remove the ability to open multiple documents at once?

I'm not talking about documents of the same type, I'm trying to open different types of documents (spreadsheets, word docs, powerpoints) but it doesn't work. However, opening documents of the same type works fine...

Anyone else have this problem? Is it truly gone or do I have a problem?

*Edit - To clarify, I mean open documents in Windows Explorer, by pressing the enter key or through the context menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean from the context menu in Windows Explorer? Nope, doesn't work here eighter. It would be possible if you decide to write your own Windows shell extension, but this would be another story.

Comment: Sigh...it's such a shame that Microsoft took away something useful. Thanks for the feedback!